# Qual a diferença entre padding e margin no CSS?

Tags: css, padding, margin

Pelo que percebo vejo um recuo em relação a outro elemento quando definidas as propriedades `left, top, right e bottom.`

Existe diferença  entre `margin` e `padding` no CSS?

Uma resposta com exemplos(imagens ou código) ajudaria bastante no entendimento da questão.

Comment: **Padding** = Interior;
**Margin** = Exterior

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway não é a mesma coisa. A pergunta citada se refere ao margin e padding no contexto Android e aqui é no CSS. Mesmo que os conceitos iniciais são parecidos, é válido ter a pergunta redirecionada para CSS, que ai as pessoas podem explorar mais esse contexto nas respostas.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway não discordo totalmente de você, mas tem uma diferença sim, o comportamento no HTML+CSS do box-model varia em certas situações, o que é especifico e não ocorre no Android. Por isto apesar da pergunta ser simplória ainda sim pode gerar boas respostas, na verdade eu não conheço quase ninguém que entenda de box-model e por isto ocorrem tantos problemas no desenvolvimento web, já que o comportamento do margin e padding variam de situação para situação em CSS. ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A grosso modo a grande diferença é:

**Margin / Margem** - Espaçamento fora do conteúdo.

**Padding / Preenchimento** - Espaçamento dentro dos limites do conteúdo.

Os estilos dos elementos HTML estão estruturados dentro de uma caixa chamada de **"The Box Model"**. Dentro dessa mesma caixa existe a hierarquia:

```
Margin Box
Border Box
Padding Box
Element Box ( O elemento em si, div, span, entre outros )
```

Tendo em conta que o limite do espaçamento do conteúdo de um elemento é a sua borda (border box). Portanto, a grande diferença neste caso será que a margem é aplicada já fora do elemento e criará espaçamento entre os restantes elementos, porém o padding irá criar espaçamento dentro do próprio conteúdo do elemento, não afetando o espaçamento dos outros elementos.

[image: Model Box]

Answer (score 21):

Basicamente `padding` é o espaço **entre o conteúdo e a borda**, enquanto `margin` é o espaço **fora da borda**, segue uma ilustração encontrada no google.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De acordo com o `w3schools`

**Padding:**
As propriedades de preenchimento CSS são usadas para gerar espaço em torno do conteúdo. O preenchimento limpa uma área ao redor do conteúdo (dentro da borda) de um elemento.

**Margin:**
As propriedades de margem CSS são usadas para gerar espaço em torno de elementos.
As propriedades de margem definem o tamanho do espaço em branco fora da borda.

Fonte:[w3 padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp),[w3 margin](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Answer (score 11):

Algumas diferenças interessantes, além das citadas nas outras respostas:

- `margin` pode ter o valor `auto`. `padding` não pode usar `auto` como valor.
- `margin:auto` pode ser útil para centralizar um elemento dentro de outro.
- `margin` pode ter valores negativos, enquanto usar valores negativos no `padding` não causa efeito.
- `padding` pode receber a cor de fundo do elemento. `margin` não recebe a cor do elemento.

Exemplos:

```css
.container {
  display:block;
  width:500px;
  background: #ffcccc
}

.box {
  background-color:#e6e6e6;
  text-align:center;
}

.box0 {
  margin:auto;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.box1 {
  margin:-10px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.box2,.box6 {;
  margin:10px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.box3 {
  padding:-10px;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
.box4 {
  padding:10px;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
.box5 {
  padding:10px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Diferenças entre padding e margin</h3>

<p>Margin pode ter valor 'auto', que pode ser útil para centralizar elementos:</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box0">
    margin:auto
  </div>
</div>
<p>Margin pode ter valores negativos.</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">
    margin:-10px
  </div><br>
  <div class="box box2">
    margin:10px
  </div>
</div>
<p>Padding não sofre alterações com valores negativos.</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box3">
    padding:-10px
  </div><br>
  <div class="box box4">
    padding:10px
  </div>
</div>
<p>Padding recebe cor do background do elemento, margin não recebe.</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box5">
    padding:10px
  </div><br>
  <div class="box box6">
    margin:10px
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

A `margin` é uma distância definida entre o seu objeto alvo e os outros objetos ao seu redor. Já o `padding` é um espaço definido dentro do seu objeto.

```css
#container {
  background: black;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.margin {
  border: 3px solid white;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.padding {
  border: 3px solid white;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="margin">MARGIN</div>
  <div class="margin">MARGIN</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="padding">PADDING</div>
  <div class="padding">PADDING</div><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Além da diferença mais comum apresentada de que `padding` é o espaço entre a e o conteúdo e já a `margin` é o espaço fora da borda, existem duas outras duas diferenças importantes.

1) O `padding` é contado como uma área clicável e já a `margin` não;

2) Se você tem dois elementos de `padding` 1px e colocar um em cima do outro, o espaço entre eles vai ser de 2px. Já se você trocar por `margin`, o espaço entre eles vai ser de 1px. A não ser que você use a propriedade `box-sizing: border-box`. Utilizando ela, mesmo utilizando margin, o espaço entre elas vai ser de 2px

Answer (score 0):

Complementando as respostas já oferecidas aqui com um pouco de código e imagem, é possível colocar `backgroud` em elementos, assim acredito que ficará mais visível a ***The box Model***.

```html
<div>
   <label style="background: lightgreen; padding: 50px"> label 1 </label>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div>
   <label style="background: gold; margin: 50px"> label 2 </label>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div>
   <label style="background: yellow; margin: 10px; padding: 10px"> label 3 </label>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div>
   <label style="background: gray; margin: 10px; padding: 10px"> label 4 </label>
   <input type="text" style="background: lightblue; margin: 15px ">
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div>
   <label style="background: gray; margin: 10px; padding: 10px"> label 5 </label>
   <input type="text" style="background: lightblue; padding: 15px ">
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div>
   <label style="background: gray; margin: 10px; padding: 10px"> label 6 </label>
   <input type="text" style="background: lightblue; padding: 15px; margin:15px ">
</div>
```

Reprodução desse código em `html`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: user2913044 bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em português. Recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais sobre o funcionando do site.

Answer (score -2):

[padding e margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJGEg.jpg)

1 - **Content** (Conteúdo) - A parte mais interna da caixa. O conteúdo pode ser uma imagem, texto, cabeçalho ou qualquer outra coisa.

2 - **Padding** (Preenchimento) - O espaço interno entre o conteúdo e a borda da sua caixa.

3 . **Border** (Borda) - O perímetro da caixa. As bordas podem ser invisíveis ou podem ser uma linha colorida grossa como a verde na foto acima.

4 - **Margin** (Margem) - O espaço externo (ou falta de espaço) ao redor da caixa.

---

[imagem comparando padding e margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJGEg.jpg)

O **preenchimento** pode ser definido como zero pixels e acima. **Ele pode alterar o tamanho de seu próprio elemento e afetar o quanto de uma cor de preenchimento ou imagem de plano de fundo é visível dentro de uma caixa.**

As **margens**, por outro lado, são essencialmente **barreiras invisíveis em torno de uma caixa. Eles definem como um elemento interage com elementos adjacentes ou a borda de uma tela**. As margens podem ser definidas como zero e acima, como preenchimento. Mas, **ao contrário do preenchimento, as margens também podem ser definidas como automáticas e podem até ter valores negativos.**