# Elemento com tamanho final diferente da definição de width e height no CSS?

Tags: html, css

## Código:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Contéudo da div.
</div>
```

- Gostaria de entender porque ao inspecionar a `div` que está no código
  pelo browser ela está com `height:202px` e `widht:402px` e não `width:300px;` e `height:100px;`?
- Caso eu queira manter os valores de `width:300px;` e `height:100px;`o que devo fazer?

## Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria uma `div` interna? Há algum outro elemento?

Comment: Lembra-te que `padding` adiciona espaçamento interno ao elemento, enquanto `margim` externo. Ambos mantém as dimensões definidas por `width` e `height` e adicionam o espaçamento. Se utilizar `margim` e inspecionar, verás que as dimensões serão mantidas.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Entendo sobre, aliás tenho até uma [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189978/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-padding-e-margin-no-css) aqui sobre seu questionamento :)

Comment: Então não sei se entendi esta pergunta. Você quer que o valor definido em `padding` seja subtraído do `width` e `height`? Se for isso, será necessário fazer manualmente, definindo `width: 200px`, pois com o `padding: 50px`, o total será de `300px`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss vou editar, talvez eu não esteja me expressando bem.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss editado.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você ta acrescentando `50px` de `padding` em todos os lados do elemento, logo você está somando isso com o tamanho já definido no `width` e no `height`mais as bordas de 1px. Para contornar esse problema com o `padding` você pode usar a propriedade `box-sizing:border-box`

```
div {
   width:300px;
   height:100px;
   border:1px solid red;
   padding:50px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Dessa forma seu elemento vai manter o `padding` porém interno e não vai aumentar o tamanho definido do seu elemento

Answer (score 2):

As propriedades `width` e `height` definem as dimensões da área de conteúdo do boxes criado pelos elementos HTML. As dimensões finais do box (largura x altura) são o resultado da soma dos valores das propriedades `width`, `padding` e `border`. Sendo assim, no seu exemplo o tamanho da `div` é resultado de:

> height = 100 + 50(padding-top) + 50(padding-bottom) + 1(border-top) +
>   1(border-bottom) = 202
>
> width= 300 + 50(padding-left) + 50(padding-right) + 1(border-left) +
>   1(border-right) = 402

A propriedade `box-sizing` altera a forma como o Box Model é calculado, incorporando os valores de `padding` e `border` à largura do box criado pelo elemento HTML. Assim você não precisa fazer cálculos para chegar às dimensões da largura e altura total do box, pois elas são exatamente aquelas que você declarou na sua regra CSS.

```css
div {
width:300px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid red;
padding:50px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
Contéudo da div.
</div>
```

Comment: E se eu quiser ela com os tamanhos que defini no CSS?

Comment: Jessica, complementa sua resposta por favor ela está correta porém faltando.

Comment: Editei a resposta, espero que tenha ficado mais claro.

Answer (score 2):

O aumento de tamanho de qualquer elemento em uma página WEB se deve a utilização do **padding**, o padding nada mais é que o espaço interno do elemento, ou seja, quando se aplica um padding de `50px`, o elemento sofrerá um aumento de `50px para top, rigth, bottom e left.`

Existem dois modos de manter a proporção do elemento ao adicionar um padding, estarei citando-os abaixo:

## Primeiro

> Escolher um valor final para minha `div 300px por 100px` definindo o espaçamento interno, levando em consideração que o espaçamento aumentará em todos os lados o elemento principal, ou seja, se o elemento possuir 300 de largura, logo ele valerá 400, pois 50 de topo e 50 de direita base 400, o mesmo é valido para a altura, então devemos subtrair 50 do valor que desejamos, neste caso queremos uma `div com 300px e 100px`, ficará assim.

```css
div.d1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 0px;
    /*É necessário por o height como 0px, pois se deixa vazio, ele assumirá um valor automático, e estragará o trabalho, eu deixei 0px 
 pois ele assume 50 de padding, o que já soma 100px da original*/
    
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
div.d2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">Ajsutando manualmente.</div>
<br>
<div class="d2"> Com Border-Box </div>
<br>
```

## Segundo

> `box-sizing: border-box`;a qual é um estilo aplicado aos elementos, mantendo a proporção original de cada um, assim não reajustando o seu tamanho com o padding.

***Observação:*** Vale ressaltar que o `border: 1px solid black`, consome 1px de cada lado do elemento, ou seja, o width passa a ser 302px;

Comment: Félix, suas divs não condizem com o que diz.

Comment: @Marconi - Confira agora

Comment: Era isso mesmo @Félix. Valeu pelos ajuste :)

Answer (score 2):

> Porque ao inspecionar a div que está no código pelo browser ela está com height:202px e widht:402px e não width:300px; e height:100px;?

Isso ocorre por causa do modelo padrão de cálculo de áreas, chamado [box sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), que é aditivo - ou seja, o tamanho final é a soma de *dimensões* + `padding` + `border` + `margin`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Caso eu queira manter os valores de `width:300px;` e `height:100px;` o que devo fazer?

Você precisa alterar o modelo para `border-box`, o que forçará o recálculo da área interna do elemento descontando tanto o `padding` quando o `border`. Exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
div {
width:300px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid red;
padding:50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
Contéudo da div.
</div>
```

Comment: Sensacional, postei a pergunta porque acho que muita gente desconhece @OnoSendai. Estou pensando em até oferecer uma recompensa aqui, pois não acho que a pergunta foi bem vista, acho que devo melhorar o titulo pra tornar mais abrangente? :)

Comment: Sempre um prazer @Marconi! 'Elemento com tamanho final diferente da definição de width e height no CSS' ou algo similar, que mencione os conceitos que o corpo da sua pergunta exibe, talvez torne mais claro o seu objetivo.

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar no titulo, estava sem saber o que colocar pra tornar mais abrangente. Vou oferecer uma recompensa nessa pergunta assim que possível. :)

Comment: Excelente! +1 @OnoSendai

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade `border-box` do CSS, como abaixo:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 50px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Contéudo da div.
</div>
```

Ela fará com que as dimensões do elemento sejam mantidas mesmo quando utilizadas outras propriedades que alterariam seu tamanho, como `padding` e `border`. Obviamente que isso é válido para `width` apenas, pois `height` se ajustará conforme o conteúdo.

Sem a utilização da mesma, o navegador manterá a *área útil* (não sei se tem um termo mais técnico) com as dimensões que você definiu e qualquer propriedade utilizada que varie o tamanho do elemento será acrescentado às dimenções do mesmo. Isto é, a área útil do elemento será 300x100, acrescentando 2 pixels em cada por causa da borda (302x102) e, finalmente, mais 100px em cada por causa do `padding`, totalizando 402x202, que são os valores inspecionados.

Comment: Era nisso que queria chegar @Anderson, você acha que a pergunta ainda está complicada de entender? Tem algo que possa melhorar? Eu desconhecia que funcionava assim, por isso decidir perguntar. Aliás até achei super interessante.