# Centralizar texto dentro de um cabeçalho fixo HTML CSS

Tags: html, html5, layout, css

Galera pode parecer bobo, mas não consigo centralizar o texto do meu menu(Ele fica um pouco mais pra baixo do que pra cima), já tentei padding, align: center, margin, não sei o por que disso acontecer, quem for responder por favor tire um tempo pra ver o código, eu queria uma explicação que eu aprenda, muito obrigado pela atenção <3
Obs*: Isso só quando eu escondo as imagens com jQuery.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.postagem {
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,.05);
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: arial;
}
#interface {
 width: 1100px;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 90px auto 10px auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.cabecalho {
 transition: 0.2s;
 top: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 35px;
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,1);
 margin: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
} 
.logo {
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 font-family: agency fb;
 font-size: 20pt;
}
#fcor {
 color: rgba(255,220,180,1);
}
/*Menu*/
.menu {
 display: block;
}
.menu h1 {
 display: none;
}
.mn {
 position: absolute;
 list-style: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 top: -20px;
 left: -40px;
 
}
.icon{
}
.im a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
.im {
 color: white;
 font-size: 14pt;
 transition: 0.3s;
 font-family: "Agency FB";
 padding: 12px;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,0);
 display: inline-block;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.im:hover {
 transition: 0.2s;
 background-color: rgba(247,136,5,1);
}
/*Postagens*/
.artigo {
 padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
}

.titulo {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 12pt;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px; 
 padding: 0px;
}

.paragrafo {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 font-family: arial;
 text-align: justify;
}
.li {
 font-size: 20pt;
 font-weight: 900;
}
.link {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.link:hover {
 font-style: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.icone {
 transition: 2s;
 border: solid white 6px;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 height: 400px;
 width: 600px;
}
#flecha {
 left: 10px;
 position: absolute; 
 margin: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
}
/*Folhas de estilo de tabela*/
.tabela {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tdn {
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 2px;
}
.vazio {
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 12px;
}
.vazio#vm {
 padding: 36px;
}
.tabt {
 background-color: white;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.subt {
 background-color: lightgray;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.ft {
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.asst {
 padding: 12px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_css/estilo.css"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).scroll(function() {
 var y = $(this).scrollTop();
 if (y < 25) {
  $('.cabecalho').css({'padding-top': '20px','padding-bottom': '20px'});
  $('.im').css({'padding': '12px'});
  $('.icon').css({'display': 'inline-block'});
 } else {
  $('.cabecalho').css({'padding-top': '5px', 'padding-bottom': '0px'});
  $('.im').css({'padding-top': '0px','padding-bottom': '0px'});
  $('.icon').css({'display': 'none'});
 }
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body class="postagem">
  <header class="cabecalho">
   <h1 class="logo">MANUAIS E PROCESSOS<span id="fcor"> INFORMÁTICA<span></h1>
   <nav class="menu">
    <h1>Menu Principal</h1>
    <ul class="mn">
     <li class="im"><a href="../index.html"><img class="icon" src="../_imagens/icasa.png"><br>Home</a></li>
     <li class="im"><a href="../index.html"><img class="icon" src="../_imagens/ilivro.png"><br>Manuais e Processos</a></li>
     <li class="im"><a href="../index.html"><img class="icon" src="../_imagens/iferramentas.png"><br>Equipamentos</a></li>
     <li class="im"><a href="../index.html"><img class="icon" src="../_imagens/ietiqueta.png"><br>Inventário</a></li>
    <ul>
  </header>
 <div id="interface">
  <article class="artigo">
   <h1 class="titulo">INSTALANDO SISTEMA OPERACIONAL</h1>
   <p class="paragrafo">
   <!--...<a class="link" href="F:\Campo Florido\Compartilhados\Informática\Comuns\planilha-modelo-formatacao.xlsx" download>Baixar o documento modelo de formatação em computadores</a><br>-->
   <span class="li">1.</span> Clique com o lado direito na bandeira do Windows ou use o atalho(Windows+X) para abrir o menu abaixo, nele escolha a opção "Sistema".<br><img src="../_imagens/renomear1.jpg" class="icone"><br>
   <span class="li">2.</span> Vá em "Renomear este computador" e coloque o nome da etiqueta do computador, após isso será necessário reiniciar o computador.<br><img class="icone" src="../_imagens/renomear2.jpg"><br>
   </p>
  <article>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Voce esta se referindo aos textos do h1?
Erros de centralizacao de texto geralmente acontecem pela falta do display block no elemento dos textos, ou se utilizou display-inline, sempre busque utilizar juntamente o vertical-align: top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Marcos como vc mesmo pediu um pouco de atenção e explicação vc deveria ao menos parar 1 minuto para dar um feedback para quem te responde. Já vi que vc tem mais de 5 perguntas abertas no site e não se deu ao trabalho de dar uma atenção para quem te responde. Então antes de pedir por atenção pense também no lado de quem parou para te responder!***

Dito isso, o seu problema é com o `height` do `.cabecalho`, quando vc define uma altura para esse elemento acaba havendo um "desequilíbrio" entre o `padding` superior e inferior, pelo simples fato do seu `.cabecalho` não estar centralizando o que está dentro dele no eixo vertical. A forma mais prática para resolver isso e tirando a altura do `.cabecalho`, assim os `paddings` ficam equilibrados e o `H1` dentro do `.cabecalho` fica centralizado.

**OBS:** Se quiser tirar a prova, basta vc aumentar a altura da classe `.cabecalho` que vc vai ver que fica ainda mais descentralizado o `H1`

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y < 25) {
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'padding-top': '20px',
      'padding-bottom': '20px'
    });
    $('.im').css({
      'padding': '12px'
    });
    $('.icon').css({
      'display': 'inline-block'
    });
  } else {
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'padding-top': '5px',
      'padding-bottom': '0px'
    });
    $('.im').css({
      'padding-top': '0px',
      'padding-bottom': '0px'
    });
    $('.icon').css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.postagem {
  background-color: rgba(255, 140, 40, .05);
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
}

#interface {
  width: 1100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 90px auto 10px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.cabecalho {
  transition: 0.2s;
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 35px; seu problema é com essa altura aqui */
  background-color: rgba(255, 140, 40, 1);
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: agency fb;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

#fcor {
  color: rgba(255, 220, 180, 1);
}


/*Menu*/

.menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu h1 {
  display: none;
}

.mn {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: -20px;
  left: 1428px;
}

.icon {}

.im a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.im {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14pt;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-family: "Agency FB";
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 140, 40, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.im:hover {
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-color: rgba(247, 136, 5, 1);
}


/*Postagens*/

.artigo {
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
}

.titulo {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.paragrafo {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: justify;
}

.li {
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover {
  font-style: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.icone {
  transition: 2s;
  border: solid white 6px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
}

#flecha {
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
}


/*Folhas de estilo de tabela*/

.tabela {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tdn {
  border: solid black 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.vazio {
  border: solid black 2px;
  padding: 12px;
}

.vazio#vm {
  padding: 36px;
}

.tabt {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid black 2px;
}

.subt {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid black 2px;
}

.ft {
  border: solid black 2px;
}

.asst {
  padding: 12px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="postagem">
  <header class="cabecalho">
    <h1 class="logo">MANUAIS E PROCESSOS<span id="fcor"> INFORMÁTICA</span></h1>
    <nav class="menu">
      <h1>Menu Principal</h1>
      <ul class="mn">
        <li class="im">
          <a href="../index.html"><img class="icon" src="http://placeskull.com/100/100"><br>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="im">
          <a href="../index.html"><img class="icon" src="http://placeskull.com/100/100"><br>Manuais e Processos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="im">
          <a href="../index.html"><img class="icon" src="http://placeskull.com/100/100"><br>Equipamentos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="im">
          <a href="../index.html"><img class="icon" src="http://placeskull.com/100/100"><br>Inventário</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="interface">
    <article class="artigo">
      <h1 class="titulo">INSTALANDO SISTEMA OPERACIONAL</h1>
      <p class="paragrafo">
        <!--...<a class="link" href="F:\Campo Florido\Compartilhados\Informática\Comuns\planilha-modelo-formatacao.xlsx" download>Baixar o documento modelo de formatação em computadores</a><br>-->
        <span class="li">1.</span> Clique com o lado direito na bandeira do Windows ou use o atalho(Windows+X) para abrir o menu abaixo, nele escolha a opção "Sistema".<br><img src="http://placeskull.com/100/100" class="icone"><br>
        <span class="li">2.</span> Vá em "Renomear este computador" e coloque o nome da etiqueta do computador, após isso será necessário reiniciar o computador.<br><img class="icone" src="http://placeskull.com/100/100"><br>
      </p>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Eu ainda não tenho reputação o suficiente para dar feedback, mas fui nos outros post e respondi e comentei agradecendo, sou novo no forum... E o problema não se resolveu, dentro do cabeçalho tem um menu lateral(No seu código ele nem  aparece) e esse menu tá como inline block, mas quando eu diminuo o padding ele n fica dentro do cabeçalho, fica mais pra baixo do cabeçalho...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RubTQ.png

Comment: Consegui achar o problema mas não sei como resolver, eu uso <br> pra quebrar a fonte pra baixo e a imagem em cima, aí eu escondo a imagem e fica só o <br>

Comment: @MarcosAurélio cara eu estava até tentando mexer no seu código, mas estou achando ele meio confuso, seria muito bom vc parar um tempinho para dar uma estudada nos atributos Position e Display do CSS, esses são os principais atributos que vc precisa saber para montar qualquer layout. Aproveite e leia esse link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189978/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-padding-e-margin-no-css. Para 1 hora para estudar pode te poupar várias horas trabalho no futuro, e vc vai aprender rápido pq são fundamentos que vc usa o tempo inteiro

Comment: Se vc pensa em seguir trabalhando com Web etc, essa dica vai te ajudar muito! No youtube tem muito material tb, com vídeos e exemplos prático e fáceis de entender. Boa sorte ai. E tente focar em dúvidas mais específica, ai vc vai aprendendo aos poucos cada parte do seu problema.