# Como aumentar o espaço entre texto e underline no CSS?

Tags: css

Quandos estamos usando um `text-decoration: underline` temos um sublinhado aplicado ao mesmo. Porém a minha dúvida é a seguinte:

- É possível alterar a distância entre o texto e o sublinhado?
- Se sim, tem alguma propriedade direta no CSS que podemos usar para colocar o espaçamento?
- Além disso, é possível usar uma imagem como underline para um texto?

Comment: Dúvida: definir `border-bottom` seria uma solução?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acredito que pode ser!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não é possível.

Os navegadores tomam o devido cuidado de utilizar apenas o espaçamento entre a *baseline* e a *beardline* do texto justamente para não alterar as dimensões do mesmo (espaço denominado *descender*).

[image]

Tanto que a *underline* se adapta conforme o tamanho do texto sem problemas:

```html
<a href=""><h1>Cabeçalho 1</h1></a>
<a href=""><h2>Cabeçalho 2</h2></a>
<a href=""><h3>Cabeçalho 3</h3></a>
<a href=""><h4>Cabeçalho 4</h4></a>
```

Perceba ainda que a fonte, por si só, fica sobre a *underline*, isto é, a linha não corta as letras que utilizam o espaçamento *descender*. E não é possível alterar essa distância justamente por não haver mais espaço no elemento. Você só tem o espaço *descender* para renderizar a linha e ela já é utilizada pelo navegador.

Há outras formas de gerar um efeito semelhante, mas todas possuem consequências. Você poderia definir a borda inferior na maneira que desejar e controlar o espaçamento com `padding-bottom`, mas isso altera as dimensões da [*border box*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189978/5878) do seu elemento, refletindo diretamente no seu layout.

```css
a:nth-child(1) {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

a:nth-child(2) {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur pharetra mi metus, ut rhoncus metus elementum eget. Ut <a href="">Bazinga</a> porttitor sapien vel massa dapibus maximus. Vivamus ullamcorper, nisi gravida aliquam pulvinar, lectus eros lacinia quam, eu imperdiet diam diam quis tortor. Integer fermentum scelerisque efficitur. In eu turpis lacus. Vestibulum <a href="">Bazinga</a> sollicitudin elit nisl, sit amet venenatis ex dapibus id. Proin in lectus sem. In vehicula ante iaculis diam consectetur rhoncus. Nam nec rhoncus turpis, vel ullamcorper neque. Morbi rhoncus tincidunt lacus at varius.</p>
```

Fiz as linhas bem grotescas para facilitar a visualização. Em uma delas, você altera o *border box* de um elemento que possui `display: inline` por padrão, o que significa que a sua linha ficará sobre o resto do texto impossibilitando a leitura; no segundo, o elemento passa a ser `display: inline-block`, o que evita da linha sobrescrever o texto, porém você quebra seu layout ficando uma linha maior que as outras.

Você poderia, também, definir uma imagem de fundo com a linha e espaçamento que desejar, mas com isso você corre o risco de ficar preso às dimensões da fonte. Se for alterar o tamanho do texto, irá precisar adequar a imagem de fundo.

Answer (score 6):

> É possível alterar a distância entre o texto e o sublinhado?

Sim como os colegas já demostraram vc pode aumentar a distancia entre o que seria um *underline* e o texto. Apenas vou acrescentar algumas coisa para completar o que vc perguntou no início.

Mas no futuro acredito que teremos novidades quanto a isso, pois a W3C tem em seus *drafts* uma propriedade dedicada para isso.

`text-underline-offset`: documentação oficial W3C https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-4/#underline-offset

*"Specifies the offset of underlines as a length. This replaces any information in the font or derived from glyph shapes / character ranges. Authors are strongly encouraged to use em units so that the offset scales with the font."*

> Se sim, tem alguma propriedade direta no CSS que podemos usar para colocar o espaçamento?

Para afasta o *underline* original, criado pelo `text-decoration: underline` no momento ainda não existe tal propriedade.

Visto que para *text-decoration* temos apenas essas 3 propriedade:

```
text-decoration-line
```

Define o tipo de decoração usada, como sublinhado ou linha.

```
text-decoration-color
```

Define a cor da linha

```
text-decoration-style
```

Define o estilo da linha, `solid`, `wavy`, `dashed` etc...

Aqui tem a documentação da Mozilla caso vc queira consultar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration#Syntax

Ainda existe a propriedade `text-underline-position` mas ela é usada para colocar sublinhado em textos na vertical etc, não é para esse tipo de coisa, apesar que ela tem uma correção para quando as "descendentes" ultrapassam a linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-underline-position-property

> Além disso, é possível usar uma imagem como *underline* para um texto?

Sim também é possível, mas leve em conta o que os outros colegas falaram. O exemplo que fiz foi com um pseudo elemento `::after`, ele sempre vai ter 100% da largura da *tag*, e como usei medidas em `rem` e `em` ele sempre vai acompanhar um proporção relativa ao tamanho do `font-size`

```css
p {
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1em;
}
span::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.2em;
    background-image: url(https://placecage.com/50/50);
}
span:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur <span>adipisicing 123 abc</span> elit. Quod dolore natus voluptates at a soluta ad nulla aspernatur <span>consequatur</span> ducimus! Adipisci reprehenderit itaque delectus, molestias magni recusandae blanditiis eos libero quisquam voluptatibus deleniti eveniet numquam corporis porro nulla laudantium quibusdam quam sunt ea temporibus ratione incidunt! Incidunt possimus rem illo quam cum minima ad aut sunt sapiente consequuntur eum inventore ipsum, dignissimos quaerat neque deserunt nisi, odit, suscipit quo molestias ut illum officia. Voluptatem magni ipsa nobis facere voluptate deserunt minima adipisci voluptas sapiente dolore placeat facilis perspiciatis repudiandae tenetur aut at, nam id voluptatum atque libero! Veritatis, qui maxime.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.sublinhado{
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<p> <span class="sublinhado">Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste </span> </p>
```

Conforme o `padding` aumentar, a linha da borda vai afastando do texto e também tem que alterar o valor de `line-height`, se não a linha ficará em cima do texto.

Comment: E se o testo tiver 10 linhas?

Comment: Essa é a questão... Com mais linhas ele vai colocar a borda só no final e não sobre cada linha.

Comment: Desconheço outra forma de alterar o espaçamento entre sublinhado e texto.

Comment: Existem várias formas, não só com borda... mas o difícil mesmo é quando tem mais de uma linha :)

Comment: Consegui fazendo essa gambiarra brava! Mas como a resposta do Anderson bem explica, não é de forma "natural".

Comment: Show @JonathandeToni, obrigado por compartilhar a sua reposta! :D

Answer (score 0):

A **n** formas de fazer isso, vou te apresentar uma delas, a opção de fazer border-bottom seria a melhor no caso de um texto grande, mas aqui tem uma outra maneira de fazer:

```
<p class="op1">
Texto sublinhado 1
</p>
<p class="op2">
Texto sublinhado 2
</p>
<style>
p.op1:before {
  content:"_______________";
  padding-top: 2px;
  position:absolute;
}
p.op2:before {
  content:"_______________";
  padding-top: 5px;
  position:absolute;
  color:red
}
</style>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/qybnu8ac/)

Comment: Sim, mas e se o texto for muito grande?

Comment: Veja [esse link](https://css-tricks.com/styling-underlines-web/), tem alguns exemplos.

Answer (score -2):

Você também pode criar uma div que sirva de box para o elemento. Terá que fazer o elemento ocupar 100% do tamanho da div, e então, colorir a border bottom da div, como se fosse um underline :)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar a propriedade css "text-underline-offset:"

```css
text-underline-offset: 2px;
```